# How To Insert Data With INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Users on a website can write articles and add photos related to articles.

The 2 tables look like this :

**ve_articles**

```
ARID | UsersId | CtaegoryId | ArticleName | ArticleText |Time
```

**ve_articles_images**

```
PhotoID | UserID | PhotoPath | Extension | ArticleID | InsertDate
```

**Query**

```
  //addArticle
    if(isset($_POST['addArticle'])){
    //get variables
        $articleCategoryID= $_POST['articleCategoryID'];
        $articleTitle= $_POST['articleTitle'];
        $articleText= $_POST['articleText'];
        $userid= $_POST['userid'];

    //insert in ve_articles
    $userarticleQ = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ve_articles (UsersId,CategoryId,ArticleName,ArticleText) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $userarticleQ->bind_param("iiss",$userid,$articleCategoryID,$articleTitle,$articleText);
    $userarticleQ->execute() or die(mysqli_error($db)); 

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

    if($userarticleQ){
        //insert the image
     $target_dir = "articles/";
    $articlephoto1 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["articlephoto1"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($articlephoto1,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["articlephoto1"]["tmp_name"]);
         if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;

        //insert in ve_survey_useranswers, UserId, QuestionId, AnswerId
        $articleimageQ = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ve_articles_images (UserID,PhotoPath,PhotoExtension,ArticleID) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $articleimageQ->bind_param("issi",$userid,$articlephoto1,$imageFileType,$articleId);
       $articleimageQ->execute() or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
       $articleimageQ->close();
        $db->close();

        $_SESSION['sucessupload']='<h4 style="text-align: center;" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" ><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>Your article  has been successfully updated.</h4>';  
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
           } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
      }
    $userarticleQ->close();
    $articleimageQ->close();
    $db->close();
    }
```

Notice how the ve_articles is join with articles_images ON ArticleID? But If I the article id is unknown until it is inserted, how can I also insert the images attachted to the article?

Comment: Can you show the code your using as this will affect the solution, but each language provides a way of getting the last insert ID for autoincrement keys.  This value is then used for the child table inserts.

Comment: Can't you do it in two steps? First create the article, then get its ID and then insert the images.

Comment: @Mindwin: What if 5 users insert articles at the same time? This could easily become messy.

Comment: @NigelRen: Yes im updating.

Comment: @NigelRen: I have updated. At first I wanted to do it in two steps but if there is a way of doing it in one step id like to see

Comment: @SebastianFarham you know what article you just inserted. Query for it using the values you just inserted.

Comment: Once you've inserted the article, use `$db->insert_id`.

Comment: _"What if 5 users insert articles at the same time?"_ - doesn't matter, the last auto-increment value you request from the database is specific to the particular database connection. _"This could easily become messy"_ - only if you let it ;) for example by over-complicating it by trying to create a complex JOIN-ed INSERT monster ... If you are worried about any of the multiple steps "going wrong" in between - then encapsulate them in a TRANSACTION, so that you can ROLLBACK the whole thing if needed.